# Can parasitic capacitances be decoupled?

Tags: pcb-design, rf, trace, decoupling, parasitic-capacitance

I was working with some IC that has a bus that is really sensitive to trace capacitance and cannot be loaded with more than 8.5 pF.

I have to bifurcate the trace to an ADC because I need to see what is being sent. This is so some algorithm will choose if the device is kept running in automatic regulation or if it's to be switched to manual.

The spacing on the PCB is quite limited. Also, it's for SHF so I have to take into account the positioning of each component so I can match the characteristic impedance properly.

Comment: Can you provide a datasheet for the ic and a section of the schematic?

Comment: sure, here you go https://www.mouser.es/datasheet/2/609/MAX2092-3128058.pdf and here's a SS of the section https://imgur.com/a/zyMGbn0. Apologies for having to keep some stuff obfuscated this is under NDA and i want to show as little as possible (my manager greenflagged this post dont wanna grab the whole arm)

Comment: So this is a 50R line that you are trying to monitor?

Comment: this one line is just a high speed analog signal. It is used to regulate the output of the MAX2092 in automatic mode. The RF line that detector is measuring it is indeed 50 ohm

Comment: Can you confirm exactly which pin is involved?

Comment: the sensitive pins are AMP_OUT and DET_VIN. Those are the sensitive ones

Comment: `really sensitive to trace capacitance` might be helpful: For a 50-Ohm trace on an FR4 board, the unit-length trace capacitance can be approximated as 3.3 fF per mil (or 3.3 pF per inch). Again, this is for a 50-Ohm trace, not for a random trace.

Comment: this seems like an interesting answer. Gonna talk to my manager about it. ATM im gonna leave it as a direct connection and once i see how it goes in the PCB design.